# PostgreSQL. How to convert varchar format dates in an existing column to date format dates

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I'm quite new to PostgreSQL. I've looked at other existing threads, the documentation and various google searches but still can't fully understand if it is possible to convert existing `date` values that are actually strings in a `varchar` column into an actual date format.

The column is named `datelaid` and has a `varchar` datatype. The table is named `init_sa_mains_1`

datelaid:

```
" "
"01-12-2011"
"01-12-2011"
" "
"01-12-2011"
" "
```

I have tried to change the data type of the column as follows, with no success:

```
ALTER TABLE init_sa_mains_1
    ALTER COLUMN datelaid TYPE date USING datelaid::date;

ALTER TABLE init_sa_mains_1
   CAST(init_sa_mains_1.datelaid as date);

ALTER TABLE init_sa_mains_1 
  ALTER COLUMN datelaid USING datelaid::date;

ALTER TABLE init_sa_mains_1
  ALTER COLUMN datelaid TYPE date;
     USING to_date(datelaid, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Could anyone please advise on a possible solution?

Comment: To what should the empty strings be converted?

Comment: Are the double quote marks literally part of your data, or are they just there to mark the edges of your literal data and make the spaces visible?

Comment: Thanks you both .. the post below solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to deal with empty strings as they can't be converted like that. But you can turn them into NULL values:

```
ALTER TABLE init_sa_mains_1
  ALTER COLUMN datelaid TYPE date;
     USING to_date(nullif(trim(datelaid),''), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```